# Hot can I use the return of localforage

Tags: vue.js, localforage

In my Vue SPA, I use localforage to store the Bearer token.

In a component, i need the token to upload files to the api.

I tried to get the localforage token:

```
            let token = localforage.getItem('authtoken')
            console.log(token)
```

It works but the result is a promise object:

```
Promise

result: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiyuIiwiaWF0IjoxNTg4MTUzMTkzLCJleHAiOjE1ODg…"

status: "resolved"
```

When i try to `console.log(token.result)` it returns `null`

How can i access the token?

Comment: Is `localforage.getItem('authtoken')` actuly returning a promise here? Also, what plugin are you using for `localforage`?

Comment: @palaѕн Yes, the promise text is copied from the console

Comment: Your question is completely explained on their documentation. https://localforage.github.io/localForage/#data-api-getitem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/#data-api-getitem) states three different approaches to reading values from the storage.

```
localforage.getItem('authtoken').then(function(value) {
    // This code runs once the value has been loaded
    // from the offline store.
    console.log(value);
}).catch(function(err) {
    // This code runs if there were any errors
    console.log(err);
});

// Callback version:
localforage.getItem('authtoken', function(err, value) {
    // Run this code once the value has been
    // loaded from the offline store.
    console.log(value);
});

// async/await
try {
    const value = await localforage.getItem('authtoken');
    // This code runs once the value has been loaded
    // from the offline store.
    console.log(value);
} catch (err) {
    // This code runs if there were any errors.
    console.log(err);
}
```